# Is there a macro to copy data from a master sheet to additional sheets based on the sheet name?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has a master tab with sales data for all states.  I subsequently have additional tabs that has the state abbreviation name.  From the master tab, I need to copy all columns of the data from the master tab to the associated state abbreviation tab.

I start by having a download file each month with just the master tab to start.  I have figured out a macro to be able to create the additional state named tabs I need, but they start out blank and need the additional data then pulled from the master tab specific to that state.

The number of lines associated with the state will changed month to month, so the macro can't be built to move just specific lines because it varies each time.  It would need to be specific to the state abbreviation (which is a column on the master tab).

I'm pretty new to macros and this is only the 3rd macro I've tried to piece together and have learned just from searching for answers online.

I tried recording a macro manually filtering and deleting the additional states, but when I use a different file and the same rows aren't deleted it doesn't successfully work.

Comment: Why don't you share a screenshot of your master worksheet and one of the desired output? Also, add some sample data as text and most importantly, the code you have tried no matter the state it is in. Use the Edit button below your post to add additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to run through the data row by row and decide where that row needs to go. Something like this would work

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
        Dim row As Long
        For row = 1 To lastRow(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master"))
            Dim state As String, rngSource As Range
            state = .Range("B" & CStr(row)).Value
            Set rngSource = .Rows(row)
            Dim lstRow As Long, rngTarget As Range
            
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(state)
                lstRow = lastRow(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(state)) + 1   
                'Note the + 1 for the first empty row
                Set rngTarget = .Rows(lstRow)
            End With
            
            rngTarget.Value = rngSource.Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I've used a function lastRow which returns the last row populated on each sheet (or Row 1 for completely emtpy sheets, so this will start populating each sheet from Row 2). Here's that function

```
Public Function lastRow(rg As Variant) As Long
'Find the last row used in a worksheet - regardless of where the data starts and ends
'and regardless of whether the data is contiguous or jagged
'Note use of Variant for the input range parameter
'This allows both worksheets and ranges to passed into the function
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = rg.Cells.Find(What:="*" _
                    , Lookat:=xlPart _
                    , LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                    , searchorder:=xlByRows _
                    , searchdirection:=xlPrevious).row
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        lr = 1  'cater for a completely empty sheet
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    lastRow = lr
End Function
```

Edit: As you are new to macros and VBA I can recommend this site [Excel Macro Mastery](https://excelmacromastery.com/) - no need to buy the book, there is also a YouTube channel and lots of code examples to download

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Groups of Data to New Worksheets

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateStateData()

    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Master"
    Const STATE_COLUMN As String = "B"
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet.
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' To keep the source worksheet intact, create a copy in a new workbook.
    
    sws.Copy
    
    ' Reference this new helper workbook.
    Dim hwb As Workbook: Set hwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    
    ' Tidy up.
    
    ' Remove filters.
    Dim hws As Worksheet: Set hws = hwb.Sheets(1)
    If hws.FilterMode Then hws.ShowAllData
    If hws.AutoFilterMode Then hws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Reference the range.
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = hws.UsedRange
    ' Sort by state column.
    hrg.Sort hrg.Columns(STATE_COLUMN), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
    ' Select cell 'A1'.
    Application.Goto Reference:=hws.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True
    ' Turn on the auto filter.
    hrg.AutoFilter
        
    ' Write the states (abbreviations) to an array.
    
    Dim StateData(), StateColumnIndex As Long, rCount As Long

    With hrg.Columns(STATE_COLUMN)
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        StateData = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1).Value
        StateColumnIndex = .Column
    End With
    
    ' Write the unique states (abbreviations) from the array to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        dict(CStr(StateData(r, 1))) = Empty
    Next r

    Erase StateData ' data is in the dictionary
    
    ' Loop through the keys of the dictionary and copy the data
    ' for each state to a separate worksheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet, drg As Range, ddrg As Range, dfrg As Range, rKey
    
    For Each rKey In dict.Keys
        ' Copy the helper worksheet to the source workbook...
        hws.Copy After:=swb.Sheets(swb.Sheets.Count)
        Set dws = swb.Sheets(swb.Sheets.Count) ' ... reference...
        dws.Name = rKey ' ... and rename it.
        ' Reference the range (has headers)...
        Set drg = dws.UsedRange ' ... and the...
        Set ddrg = drg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1) ' ... data range (no headers).
        ' Filter the range (has headers) state column by not equal to state.
        drg.AutoFilter StateColumnIndex, "<>" & rKey
        ' Reference the fitered rows using the data range (no headers).
        Set dfrg = ddrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ' Turn off the auto filter...
        dws.AutoFilterMode = False
        dfrg.Delete xlShiftUp ' ... and delete the filtered rows.
    Next rKey
        
    ' Clean up.
    
    ' Close the helper workbook...
    hwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    sws.Select ' ... and select the source worksheet.
    
    'swb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "State data created.", vbInformation

End Sub
```